# "TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()" - Linear Search on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linear-search

I am kinda new on Python and today I wanted to make a linear search algorithm but I'm having problems with `len(list)`:

```
def linearSearch(list, targetValue):
    for i in range(0, len(list)):
        if list[i] == targetValue:
            return i #function stops

    return -1

# MAIN

myList = [3, 2, 8, 1, 10]

location = linearSearch(list, 3)
print(location)
```

I expected the output to give nothing or `-1` because I'm still testing
But I keep getting this Error Message.

Comment: you need to use `myList` as a parameter, not `list` - `linearSearch(myList, 3)`

Comment: You meant to type linearSearch(myList) but typed list instead of myList. list is a type.

Comment: Side-note: This is one of several reasons to never name a variable `list` (or any other built-in type); it increases the risk of a mismatch like this.

Comment: Additional side-notes since you're new to Python: 1) [Python's style guide calls for `lower_case_with_underscores` names for functions and variables](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) 2) Your `linearSearch` function is reinventing `list.index`, and doing so in a dangerous way (because if the caller forgets to check the return value, `-1` is a perfectly legal index in a Python `list`). 3) If you had to write this, you'd want to use `for i, val in enumerate(mylist): if val == targetvalue: return i` to avoid repeated indexing and use useful names.

Answer (score 0):

'list' is a reserved word for the data type. You should avoid using it for your variables. That's why you get the error, interpreted thinks it's the list as in the data structure.

Comment: Also avoid using it in function definitions etc.

Comment: `list` is not a reserved word. It's perfectly legal to use it for variable names, it's just a terrible idea. In this case, the code would have worked just fine if they'd passed `myList` as the argument instead of `list`, it just would have been confusing (and problematic if they needed the `list` constructor in the function).